# How to differentiate Ubuntu and Debian in CMake?

Tags: cmake, debian

I need to differentiate Ubuntu and Debian in a CMakelists.txt.
Is someone know how to do that ?
I tried to use CMAKE_SYSTEM and CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME but it returns only informations about the Linux kernel...

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

file(READ "/etc/issue" ETC_ISSUE)
string(REGEX MATCH "Debian|Ubuntu" DIST ${ETC_ISSUE})

if(DIST STREQUAL "Debian")
    message(STATUS ">>>> Found Debian <<<<")
elseif(DIST STREQUAL "Ubuntu")
    message(STATUS ">>>> Found Ubuntu <<<<")
else()
    message(STATUS ">>>> Found unknown distribution <<<<")
endif()

add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

This reads the **/etc/issue** file, which contains the name of the distribution you are using, into the **ETC_ISSUE** variable. 
Then you grep for Debian or Ubuntu and save the result in **DIST**. 
Now you can check **DIST** using the **if** command.

Comment: This solution works on Debian derivatives like Ubuntu, but not on Fedora.  Unfortunately Fedora returns `Kernel`.

Comment: ` /etc/os-release` seems to be a bit more reliable.